# How to overrite firebase storage url value Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

hey guys after checking everything on stack overflow and checking out the documentation you can find here :

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/delete-files

I still cannot figure out how to change the value at a url I have this code:

```
  let uploadData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.profileImage.image!, 0.3)

            staticValuesForData.instance.dataBaseUserref.child(self.currentUserUid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value , with: { (snapshot) in
                if let imageName = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: staticValuesForData.instance.profilePicStorageUrl).value as? String {
                    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child("\(imageName)")



                    storageRef.putData(uploadData!, metadata: nil, completion: { (metaData, error) in
                        if error != nil{
                            print(error!)
                            return
                        }

                        if let profileImageURL = metaData?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString{

                            staticValuesForData.instance.dataBaseUserref.child(self.currentUserUid).child(staticValuesForData.instance.profileUrl).setValue("\(profileImageURL)")

                        }

                    })

                }
            })
```

Which does nothing more then change the image in my profile picture child in firebase storage which looks like this :

[image]

The name stays the same on purpose to override the previous image (profilePicStorageUrl is unique string per user)

**my question is this**, why does the "link" (https://firebase...) fail to load the new image when i replace the existing picture with a new one, yet it has the same name and appears to be overwritten in firebase storage?

[image]

**Elaborated Question: **

profile url and picUrl above both point to the same point in storage as far as I know , yet when the old picture is overwritten with the new one , the objects in my firebase database that still have the old url do not load the new picture , Why? Is there a fix for this or any way i can use the old url and overrite the value at it ? thanks for your help

**Update**

the problem can be boiled down to this , which I feel will be easier for those who come by to understand quicker.

```
storageRef.putData(uploadData!, metadata: nil, completion: { (metaData, error) in
                        if error != nil{
                            print(error!)
                            return
                        }

                        if let profileImageURL = metaData?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString{

                            staticValuesForData.instance.dataBaseUserref.child(self.currentUserUid).child(staticValuesForData.instance.profileUrl).setValue("\(profileImageURL)")

                        }

                    })
```

this meta data has a downloadstring() method , yet I cannot seem to find a way to change the download string , how can i set the download string to an existing download string that was created when the user was made? Is this a solution for the above problem?

Comment: How are you loading and displaying images, using some library?

Comment: Yes i am i have my own jpeg compression extension @ZassX see my update

Comment: Ok, just asking because I was experiencing same thing but the problem was image caching (it didn't detect new image since it had same name). The thing is that url is changed each time new file is uploaded: that is why I never saved image URL in database but instead saved image storage KEY. Firebase also provides library to load images by just giving file reference. It is very simple and I have implemented it few times already, works nice! Check out here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#downloading_images_with_firebaseui

Comment: @ZassX thanks alot!!

Comment: Sounds like an answer :) @ZassX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered in comments already but I am adding it here (easier to see) in case anyone else has same problem or needs some guides regarding this problem.

> The thing is that url is changed each time new file is uploaded: that
>   is why I never saved image URL in database but instead saved image
>   storage KEY. The thing is that Firebase provides library to load
>   images by just giving file reference. It is very simple and I have
>   implemented it few times already, works nice!
>
> Check it out here:
>   https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#downloading_images_with_firebaseui